# What is the position rule in sports when multiple contestants are on the same previous position?

Tags: rules, terminology

Assume you have two contestant on position 1. What is the position of the next contestant? 2 (2nd time/score) or 3 (2 better then him/her)?

Is there a rule or sports law if a podium/classification has empty positions if several contestants are on a previous position?

What sports have empty standing position and which have consecutive position regardless of now many contestants are there before a certain one?

Is there a rule for it? What is the terminology I can use to describe this?

Answer (score 6):

Different sports organizations have different rules, but in general, if you have two participants that are tied for first place, the next participant is in third place, not second.

Consider a race with a leader board. The top three participants are in first, second, and third places. Now let's say that the first two pull away, and the third drops back to a distant third place. If the first two participants keep passing each other, the one on third place is still in third place. And if the first two are right next to each other, the one in third doesn't suddenly jump to second place; he still has two people in front of him, so no matter what happens with them, he's got third until he passes one of them.